# How to achieve swipe between Div elements in Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm doing an app with Ionic 1. I need to swipe the screen inside a div element. Kindly suggest me a plan.

My HTML is:

```
<div ng-show="All" class="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="Earned" class="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="Redeemed" class="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft

Comment: Can we do animations while swiping? Kindly suggest if possibilities

Comment: what kind of animations and and when u want to show them

Comment: When I swipe left or right, if it shows like fade in fade out, that will be good. Or any better effects also. Now the page is just getting changed which is not more attractive

Comment: Then as Edision suggested go through the ng animate and make those mentioned changes

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is controller

```
   angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.warn = function () {
      alert("do your stuff");
    };
  });
```

and html `<div class="swipe" on-swipe-left="warn()">Swipe div</div>`

for more look this pen http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/ZKbJaw

Comment: It's working! Can we do animations while swiping? Kindly suggest if possibilities.

Comment: Please tell me the way to do that

Comment: you can use `ngAnimate`  take a look on this https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/

Comment: Working. But have a problem. I'm having 4 div elements each having some data. When I'm swiping, the existing data also appearing for a while and after animation only it is disappearing. Any solutions for this? 

<div ng-show="Topupdata" class="list animated zoomIn" on-swipe-left="net1()"  on-swipe-right="ftt()">

This is the tag I'm using